# Розробка чи розроблення програмного забезпечення

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова, віддієслівні-іменники

В СУМ-11 присутні обидва слова:

> ***[РОЗРО́БЛЕННЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozroblennja)***  Дія за значенням розробити, розробляти.
>
> ***[РОЗРО́БКА](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozrobka)*** 1. Дія за значенням розробити, розробляти. 2. Результат
>   всебічного вивчення, дослідження якого-небудь питання, якоїсь
>   проблеми.

Стаття Вікіпедії має назву [Розробка програмного забезпечення](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F)

Сайт [OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/) рекомендує:

> В українській мові для позначення процесу рекомендовано уникати
>   скалькованих віддієслівних іменників жіночого роду.
>
> Замініть іменник ***розробка*** на варіант: ***розроблення***, або перебудуйте
>   речення, використавши дієслово ***розробляти, розробити.***

[image]

*Як все ж таки правильно сказати **розробка** чи **розроблення** програмного забезпечення?*

Answer (score 3):

Погоджуюсь із другим джерелом. Українській мові при позначенні процесу властиві закінчення -ння. Особисто я завжди використовую "розроблення" у значенні процесу (адже розробляти ПЗ - це саме процес). А "розробка" - це вже результат дії, наприклад, програмна розробка.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE!
Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того,
що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише
на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень.
А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо.
Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також
[«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/).
Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою.
Для цього натисніть [edit].